# SQL Order By and "Not-So-Much Group"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, sql-order-by

Lets say I have a table:
    --------------------------------------
    |  ID  |  DATE  |  GROUP  |  RESULT  |
    --------------------------------------
    | 1    | 01/06  | Group1  | 12345    |
    | 2    | 01/05  | Group2  | 54321    |
    | 3    | 01/04  | Group1  | 11111    |
    --------------------------------------

I want to order the result by the most recent date at the top but group the "group" column together, but still have distinct entries.  The result that I want would be:

```
1 | 01/06 | Group1 | 12345
3 | 01/04 | Group1 | 11111
2 | 01/05 | Group2 | 54321
```

What would be a query to get that result?

thank you!

EDIT:

I'm using MSSQL. I'll look into translating the oracle query into MS SQL and report my results.

EDIT

SQL Server 2000, so OVER/PARTITION is not supported =[

Thank you!

Comment: not necessisarily distinct entries, but i don't want to combine entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table table (
    ID int not null,
    [DATE] smalldatetime not null,
    [GROUP] varchar(10) not null,
    [RESULT] varchar(10) not null
)

insert @table values (1, '2009-01-06', 'Group1', '12345')
insert @table values (2, '2009-01-05', 'Group2', '12345')
insert @table values (3, '2009-01-04', 'Group1', '12345')


select t.*
from @table t
inner join (
    select 
        max([date]) as [order-date],
        [GROUP]
    from @table orderer
    group by
        [GROUP]
) x
    on t.[GROUP] = x.[GROUP]
order by
    x.[order-date] desc,
    t.[GROUP],
    t.[DATE] desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify what RDBMS you are using.  This answer is for Oracle, may not work in other systems.

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY group) DESC, group, date DESC
```

Comment: +1 for your answer . but for column name group getting error.If we change it will work.

Comment: Is there a MS SQL translation for this query? It's not recognizing PARTITION, though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx does show support for it.

Answer (score 1):

use an `order by` clause with two params:

```
...order by group, date desc
```

this assumes that your date column does hold dates and not varchars

Comment: This will order by the group, alphabetically.  He wants the groups ordered by the most recent date within that group

Comment: HOw about if you swap them, order by date desc, group asc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.myID,
 table2.mydate, 
 table2.mygroup, 
 table2.myresult
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mygroup FROM testtable as table1) as grouptable
JOIN testtable as table2
 ON grouptable.mygroup = table2.mygroup
ORDER BY grouptable.mygroup,table2.mydate
```

SORRY, could NOT bring myself to use columns that were reserved names, rename the columns to make it work :)

this is MUCH simpler than the accepted answer btw.